# node.js file download Also, no errors come out

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, fs

My code

downLoadImg(imagePath) = vue.js Code

exports.download = js Code

```
downLoadImg(imagePath){
        const url = this.$utils.makePathVariableURL('webportal', 'wb', 'addon-file', 'download-image');
        const params = {};
        params.imagePath = imagePath;

        this.$http.get(url, {params: params}).then(() => {
          
        }).catch(function (err) {});
      },

exports.download = function (req, res){
  let uploadFilePath = req.query.imagePath;
  var fileName = path.basename(uploadFilePath);
  var mimeType = mime.getType(uploadFilePath);
  var stream = null;
  var isExists = fs.existsSync(uploadFilePath, (exists) => {});

  try {
    if (isExists) {
      stream = fs.createReadStream(uploadFilePath);
    } else {
      res.send('file is not found');
      return;
    }
  }catch(err){}
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",  "*");
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename='+ fileName);
  res.set('Content-type', mimeType);

   stream.pipe(res);
}
```

The file cannot be downloaded. Also, no errors come out...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't post images of your code, as it is difficult to read and test. Instead, copy the code and paste it into a code block in your question.

Comment: Changed to code :)

Comment: never use blocking code in a webserver unless absolutely necessary. no error event attached to readstream. please check if you can download using curl/wget to make sure server is behaving as expected